# How to count the cell by group in R

Tags: r

Sorry for change the question for I cannot ask for a new one.

Original data is

```
      D     T C    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1  2000 A    
2     2  2000 A    
3     3  2000 A    
4     1  2000 B    
5     5  2000 B    
6     6  2000 B    
7     1  2001 A    
8     2  2001 A    
9     3  2001 B
```

What I need is

```
      D     T C     count
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <int>
1     1  2000 A         3
2     2  2000 A         3
3     3  2000 A         3
4     1  2000 B         3
5     5  2000 B         3
6     6  2000 B         3
7     1  2001 A         2
8     2  2001 A         2
9     3  2001 B         1
```

I want count the cell D by_group(T,C)

However the answer code

```
sample%>%group_by(T,C) %>% mutate(count = n_distinct(D))
```

Which count is 5 for all

Answer (score 1):

If we want to create a column of counts, use `add_count

```
library(dplyr)
sample <- sample %>% 
   add_count(T, C, name = 'count')
```

-output

```
sample
 D    T C count
1 1 2000 A     3
2 2 2000 A     3
3 3 2000 A     3
4 1 2000 B     3
5 5 2000 B     3
6 6 2000 B     3
7 1 2001 A     2
8 2 2001 A     2
9 3 2001 B     1
```

#### data

```
sample <- structure(list(D = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L), T = c(2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L), C = c("A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: not work the result is ```structure(list(n = 3L, .groups = "drop"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))``

Comment: fwiw it works fine for me.

Comment: @akrun I edit the question again for I cannot ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```r
df <- structure(list(cty_fips = structure(c("01001", "01001", "01001", 
                                            "01001", "01001", "01001", "01001", "01001", "01001", "01003", 
                                            "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003", 
                                            "01003", "01005", "01005"), format.stata = "%-9s"), 
                     congressional_district = structure(c("02", 
                                                          "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "01", "01", "01", 
                                                          "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02"), format.stata = "%-9s"), 
                     congress_number = structure(c(109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 
                                                   115, 116, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 108, 
                                                   109, 110), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
                     state_name = structure(c("AL", 
                                              "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
                                              "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL"), format.stata = "%-9s"), 
                     congressionaldistrict = structure(c("AL 2", "AL 2", "AL 2", 
                                                         "AL 2", "AL 2", "AL 2", "AL 2", "AL 2", "AL 2", "AL 1", "AL 1", 
                                                         "AL 1", "AL 1", "AL 1", "AL 1", "AL 1", "AL 1", "AL 1", "AL 2", 
                                                         "AL 2"), format.stata = "%-9s")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))

# using table
table(df$congressional_district, df$congress_number) |>
  melt() |> 
  `colnames<-`(c('congressional_district', 'congress_number', 'count')) 

# using tapply
tapply(df$cty_fips, list(df$congressional_district, df$congress_number), length) |>
  melt() |> 
  `colnames<-`(c('congressional_district', 'congress_number', 'count'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. And I may not clear ask the question. So I edit again for my question.